# Html element interpreted as text

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I have a problem with some Html tags. They are interpreted as text i think.

In my JS file I have printed the elements into the console:

```
console.log(groessenTrList[i]);
console.log(groessenTrList[i].firstChild);
```

The chrome developer tool shows this:

[image]

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqqaQ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUubA.png)

When I print the whole element to the console everything seems to be ok.
The children are fine and the html seems to be right.

But when I print the child element its interpreted as text and i dont know why.

The whole html comes from a spring backend

```
@PostMapping("/editArtikel")
@ResponseBody
public String editArtikel(String artikelID, HttpSession session) {
    ...
    String htmlToPrint = doc.outerHtml();
    return htmlToPrint;
}
```

I use Jsoup to create the html code.

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Use `.firstChildElement`. `.firstChild` will be a `#TextNode` (e.g. newline)

Comment: Use `.firstElementChild` instead of `.firstChild`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But now the Element is "undefined"